# Passing instance variables in nested partials in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having difficulty passing instance variables in nested partials. Here is what I have done.

In controller Own:

```
def home
  @item = "some values"
  @ref = "some other values"
end
```

Then I have a home page "home.html.erb", in which I rendered "_product_table.html.erb":

```
<%= render "own/product_table", :item => @items, :ref => @ref %>
```

Then, in "_product_table.html.erb", I have to render "_product.html.erb":

```
<% @items.each do |item|%>
  <%= render "own/product", :item => item, :ref => @ref %>
<% end %>
```

I can't understand why the `ref` variable is not available in the "_product.html.erb" partial.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. So `home.html.erb` renders `product_table.html.erb` which renders `product.html.erb` which renders `_product.html.erb`?

Comment: home.html.erb renders _product_table.html.erb and the _product_table.html.erb renders _product.html.erb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `ref` as argument to the partial in `home.html.erb`, so in `_product_table.html.erb` you should use it similarly to `item`, not as instance variable:

```
<% @items.each do |item|%>
  <%= render "own/product", :item => item, :ref => ref %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yes I tried that then I in href tag I did something like this. <div class="product" data-ref="<% ref %>"><a href="<%somevalues%>" data-ref = "<%ref%>">></div> but the values of data attribute did not append in the url on mouse hover which we see in the bottom left corner of chrome

Comment: Use `<%= ref %>` instead of `<% ref %>`.